# mongodb container start failed with error:IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db, terminating

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

mongodb docker container start failed with errors: IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db, terminating

I use offical mongodb Dockerfile to build the container, and use docker-compose to start it.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

# add our user and group first to make sure their IDs get assigned consistently, regardless of whatever dependencies get added
RUN groupadd -r mongodb && useradd -r -g mongodb mongodb

RUN  echo "deb http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse" > /etc/apt/sources.list \
    && echo "deb http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
    && echo "deb http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
    && echo "deb http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list 

RUN export all_proxy=http:192.168.1.177:1080

RUN set -eux; \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        ca-certificates \
        jq \
        numactl \
    ; \
    if ! command -v ps > /dev/null; then \
        apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends procps; \
    fi; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# grab gosu for easy step-down from root (https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases)
ENV GOSU_VERSION 1.11
# grab "js-yaml" for parsing mongod's YAML config files (https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml/releases)
ENV JSYAML_VERSION 3.13.0

RUN mkdir ~/.gnupg && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf

RUN set -ex; \
    \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        wget \
    ; \
    if ! command -v gpg > /dev/null; then \
        apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gnupg dirmngr; \
    fi; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*; \
    \
    dpkgArch="$(dpkg --print-architecture | awk -F- '{ print $NF }')"; \
    wget -O /usr/local/bin/gosu "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/$GOSU_VERSION/gosu-$dpkgArch"; \
    wget -O /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/$GOSU_VERSION/gosu-$dpkgArch.asc"; \
    export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)"; \
    gpg --batch --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys B42F6819007F00F88E364FD4036A9C25BF357DD4; \
    gpg --batch --verify /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc /usr/local/bin/gosu; \
    command -v gpgconf && gpgconf --kill all || :; \
    rm -r "$GNUPGHOME" /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc; \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gosu; \
    gosu --version; \
    gosu nobody true; \
    \
    wget -O /js-yaml.js "https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml/raw/${JSYAML_VERSION}/dist/js-yaml.js"; \
# TODO some sort of download verification here
    \
    apt-get purge -y --auto-remove wget

RUN mkdir /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

ENV GPG_KEYS E162F504A20CDF15827F718D4B7C549A058F8B6B
RUN set -ex; \
    export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)"; \
    for key in $GPG_KEYS; do \
        gpg --batch --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key"; \
    done; \
    gpg --batch --export $GPG_KEYS > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mongodb.gpg; \
    command -v gpgconf && gpgconf --kill all || :; \
    rm -r "$GNUPGHOME"; \
    apt-key list

# Allow build-time overrides (eg. to build image with MongoDB Enterprise version)
# Options for MONGO_PACKAGE: mongodb-org OR mongodb-enterprise
# Options for MONGO_REPO: repo.mongodb.org OR repo.mongodb.com
# Example: docker build --build-arg MONGO_PACKAGE=mongodb-enterprise --build-arg MONGO_REPO=repo.mongodb.com .
ARG MONGO_PACKAGE=mongodb-org-unstable
ARG MONGO_REPO=repo.mongodb.org
ENV MONGO_PACKAGE=${MONGO_PACKAGE} MONGO_REPO=${MONGO_REPO}

ENV MONGO_MAJOR 4.1
ENV MONGO_VERSION 4.1.10
# bashbrew-architectures:amd64 arm64v8 s390x
RUN echo "deb http://$MONGO_REPO/apt/ubuntu bionic/${MONGO_PACKAGE%-unstable}/$MONGO_MAJOR multiverse" | tee "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/${MONGO_PACKAGE%-unstable}.list"

RUN set -x \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        ${MONGO_PACKAGE}=$MONGO_VERSION \
        ${MONGO_PACKAGE}-server=$MONGO_VERSION \
        ${MONGO_PACKAGE}-shell=$MONGO_VERSION \
        ${MONGO_PACKAGE}-mongos=$MONGO_VERSION \
        ${MONGO_PACKAGE}-tools=$MONGO_VERSION \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/mongodb \
    && mv /etc/mongod.conf /etc/mongod.conf.orig

RUN mkdir -p /data/db /data/configdb \
    && chown -R mongodb:mongodb /data/db /data/configdb \
    && chmod g+w -R /data/db \
    && chmod g+w -R /data/configdb

VOLUME /data/db /data/configdb

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 27017
CMD ["mongod"]
```

and docker-compose below:

```
  mongodb:
    build: ./dockerfiles/mongodb
    volumes:
      - ./data/mongodb/db:/data/db
      - ./data/mongodb/configdb:/data/configdb
    ports:
      - 7017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=super
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
    restart: always
```

I expect the container start successfully. But i got failure with :IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db, terminating

If i remove volumes sections, It works! 
The host is ubuntu18.04, and /data is writeable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had solved my problem le 老铁!

AS i use vmware to start an Ubuntu server, and shared a folder with windows 7. The container volume on the shared folder.

check the inspect information of the mongodb container.

```
 "Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/mnt/hgfs/ubuntu/dockers/data/mongodb/configdb",
            "Destination": "/data/configdb",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        },
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/mnt/hgfs/ubuntu/dockers/data/mongodb/db",
            "Destination": "/data/db",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        }
    ],
```

the Source contains string "/mnt/hgfs/ubuntu" tell us: It shared folder!